# Using getAnchorByText, but want the 2nd of 2 links on the page

Tags: java, htmlunit

On my page, there are 2 links with the same anchor text.

I am using HtmlUnit to get the link by the anchor text.

The call to:

```
page.getAnchorByText("1");
```

Seems to always get the first occurrance, is there a way to get the 2nd occurance if there are 2 links?

Answer (score 1):

Not using that method.  But you can instead call `getAnchors()` and get a `List<HtmlAnchor>` -- if you iterate over that and call `getTextContent()` on each anchor, you can check against whatever string you want and get all of the matches yourself.